# How to change flushright in order to set space between margin and text?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

In my table I have got something like this:

```
\multicolumn{1}{p{12cm}}{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\small\begin{flushright}\noindent keywords:\\ aaa\\bbb\\ccc\end{flushright}} \\
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to set space between right margin and text (e.g. 1cm)? After text is flushrighted, it is right-aligned and this space equals zero.

Comment: Please provide a *full* minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You should use `\raggedleft` rather than the `flushright` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column specifier `@` can be used to set the space to `1cm` at the right side of the cell:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{12cm}@{\hspace{1cm}}|}{%
  \raggedleft
  \small
  \rule{0pt}{1cm}%
  keywords:\\
  aaa\\
  bbb\\
  ccc
}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, it looks quite odd, but I do not have a clue, what your intentions of formatting the table are.

---

Another interpretation. Only `keywords:` is moved 1cm to the left in a right-aligned cell:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{12cm}|}{%
  \raggedleft
  \small
  \rule{0pt}{1cm}%
  keywords:\hspace{1cm}\null\\
  aaa\\
  bbb\\
  ccc
}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- LaTeX kills previous glue (`\unskip`) at the end of a cell (usually to get rid of a trailing space). Therefore an empty box (`\null` = `\hbox{}`) is added after `\hspace` to hide the latter from `\unskip`.

---

Another shooting into the dark:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{12cm}|}{%
  \raggedleft
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ }r@{}}
    \rule{0pt}{1cm}%
    keywords:&\\
    &aaa\\
    &bbb\\
    &ccc
  \end{tabular}
}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it does not work as I expected to. My intention was not to expand width of the whole cell, but to move "keywords" left from the right edge (space=1cm) with right-aligning of it. Your solution add indicated space to the width of the cell.

Comment: Part: \hspace{1cm}\null\\ from the 2nd interpretation was that I was looking for! Thanks a lot!